# Alter table error massage in any changes in particular database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE production.product_colors (
color_id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
color_name VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
created_at DATETIME2
);
```

I created table production,product_colors and column name created_at datetime2 data type and now I want change data type but I cannot. Not only one table, I cannot alter any table in the database.

```
ALTER TABLE production.product_colors
ADD CONSTRAINT df_current_time 
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FOR created_at;
```

When I am running above query I get this error:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TR_ALTERTABLE, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 86]
Invalid object name 'TableSchemaChanges'.
```

I cannot understand why this error occurring. I searched google and nothing helps me.

Comment: Seems a DDL trigger in the database is referencing a table that was dropped. Drop or correct the database DDL trigger.

Comment: Go ask the person or team that wrote this trigger or manages your database server instance. Someone knows about this and can help you figure out what to do.

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue caused by schema. Please double-check it.

Here is a correct sample using 'dbo' schema.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c0e59e40ca9389b149434696ea52dc3d)

[Please refer to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/enable-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

The following example creates a DDL trigger safety with database scope, and then disables and enables it.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER safety   
ON DATABASE   
FOR DROP_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE   
AS   
   PRINT 'You must disable Trigger "safety" to drop or alter tables!'   
   ROLLBACK;  
GO  
DISABLE TRIGGER safety ON DATABASE;  
GO  
ENABLE TRIGGER safety ON DATABASE;  
GO
```

Comment: The syntax the OP is perfectly fine. Your answer is not relevant to the question being asked.

Comment: @Sean lange, Do you see Shashidhar R's sharing error in his side?

Comment: Yes. That is in fact the reason they posted a question. Do you see the error message? "Invalid object name 'TableSchemaChanges'". That is not in their code. And if you don't believe that the syntax is valid try copying and pasting the create table and alter table statements they posted. They are fine. That indicates there is likely a ddl trigger that is failing.

Comment: Thank your comment. I think the trigger exists in the different schemas. It is possible that the trigger exists in the database. Hence, you are right.